# Chart JS remove x-axis and y a-xis visibility

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a line chart in Chartjs. I want to be able to remove the x-axis and y-axis data from visibilty so it only shows the line.

Below is the codepen that I am working with.

[codepen.io](https://codepen.io/eddydomingo/pen/qBPrpro)

The code I have is the below.

```
<html>
<style>
    body{
        background:none;
    }
    canvas {
        background-color: white;
        color:black;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
<body>
<canvas id="myChart" style="width:100%;max-width:600px"></canvas>

<script>
var xValues = [50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150];
var yValues = [7,8,8,9,9,9,10,11,14,14,15];

new Chart("myChart", {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: xValues,
    datasets: [{
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,255,1.0)",
      borderColor: "rgba(0,0,255,0.1)",
      data: yValues
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {display: false},
    scales: {
       xAxes: [{
      gridLines: {
         display: false
      },
      
   }],
   yAxes: [{
      gridLines: {
         display: false
      }
   }]
    }
  }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ticks: { display: false }` will take care of that.

```
    scales: {
       xAxes: [{
         ticks: {
           display: false
         },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          display: false
        },
        gridLines: {
         display: false
        }
      }],
    }
```

Comment: gridLines display false did not work for me. Does anyone have a solution?